# Invalid Filter Template Error Django 1.11

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

This is my filter:
    from django import template

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='addition')
def addition(*args):
    return round(sum(list(args)), 1)
```

This is the error:

```
Invalid filter: 'addition'
```

In my template:

```
{% load static %}
{% load math_filters %}
```

This is the filter in the template:

```
`{{ ASEL.total_time|addition:"AMEL.total_time, ASES.total_time, AMES.total_time" }}`
```

I want the filter `addition` to accept any number of arguments and add the numbers together

I've followed the docs to the T and still can't get the tag to register.

`templatetags` dir is at the same level as `models.py` and contains `__init__.py`

I'm totally lost. Any ideas?

Comment: A filter template can only take *at most two* parameters.

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Comment: According to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

"To ease the creation of these types of tags, Django provides a helper function, simple_tag. This function, which is a method of django.template.Library, takes a function that *accepts any number of arguments*, "

Comment: Moreover, you must register `your_app.templatetags.math_filters` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Just tried that, but it didn't work. According to the docs:
    The app that contains the custom tags must be in 
    INSTALLED_APPS in order for the {% load %} tag to 
    work. 
Not the 'app.templatetags.filter' in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Mostly, you register a tag, but use it like filter.

Comment: I understand that, but why isn't django recognizing that it exists?

Comment: @user2498975: you mix the concepts of a template *tag* with a template *filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Limitations of *template filters*

> I want the filter addition to accept any number of arguments and add the numbers together.

A custom template filter *can* not take more than one parameter on the right (and the implicit parameter on the left), as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

> Custom filters are just Python functions that **take one or two
>   arguments**:
>
> 1. The value of the variable (input) – not necessarily a string.
> 2. The value of the argument – this can have a default value, or be left out altogether.

Personally I do not really understand why you want to do that anyway. You could make the granularity of the tag *finer*, and write it like:

```
{{ ASEL.total_time|add:AMEL.total_time|add:ASES.total_time|add:AMES.total_time|some_round }}
```

(where you can implement `some_round` template filter to round the result).

You can also solve this by taking one optional parameter, for example a string, and then perform string processing, but this will usually only result in more complicated code, probably bugs included.

## Using *template tags*

You can however define a *template tag*, template tags can take *multiple* parameters (both positional and named ones). For example:

```
#  app/templatetags/math_filters.py

@register.simple_tag
def addition(*args):
    return round(sum(list(args)), 1)
```

Then you can write it like:

```
{% load math_filters %}

{% addition ASEL.total_time AMEL.total_time AMES.total_time %}
```

or if you want to store the result in a variable:

```
{% load math_filters %}

{% addition ASEL.total_time AMEL.total_time AMES.total_time as some_variable %}
```

> **Note**: since variable can contain all kinds of type, you might want to make the template tag more *flexible* to interpret strings, etc. as numerical values.

Comment: Wow, I was really wrapped up between the two. Filters use the 
`{{ value|filter:"arg }}` format where, 
tags use `{% tag arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 %}`

I like the idea of
 `{{ASEL.total_time|add:AMEL.total_time|add:ASES.total_time|add:AMES.total_time|some_round }}` 
but I might also need to subtract which is why wanted a `math` module to build those needs. I really appreciate you taking the time to write such an informative reply.

Cheers!

Comment: @user2498975: in that case it might indeed be better to write some mathematical operations as template tags. I would however advice not to write too much "business logic" into a template (well many uses see this as a *bad* idea, since after a while the business logic is scattered in several layers, and repeated in several templates). Template tags and/or filters should mainly be used to *render* results.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm doing it this way since the math will be simple and all of the quantities have been created in my models. This way, I can write 10 context queries and get 60 template entries as opposed to having 60 contexts which I think would be a far greater offense.